# Comprehension list and output <generator object.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002C392688C78>

Tags: python

This may be a simple question, but I'm usually bad at comprehension lists.

I have a few dicts inside a dict like this:

```
main_dict = {
 'a': { 
    'a1':[1,2,3,...], 
    'a2':[2,4,6,...] 
    }
 'b': {
    'b1':[0,2,4,...],
    'b2':[1,3,5,...] 
    }
 }
```

Except those dicts are pretty big.

**What I want is to add this into a log (I'm using logger) but I don't want all the data, because that would make the log huge in no time and it makes it difficult to read. So I tried this in order to store only the first 10 entrys of each sub dict:**

```
self.logger.debug('Recieved: {}'.format(self.main_dict[x][i][:10] for x in self.main_dict.keys() for i in self.main_dict[x].keys()))
```

But the return is an object:

> ' generator object.locals.genexpr at 0x000002C392688C78'

So I did a separated test with this:

```
main_dict = {
    'A':{
        'a1': [1,2,3],
        'a2': [4,5,6]
        },
    'B': {
        'b1': [0,2,4],
        'b2': [1,3,5]
        }
    }

print([main_dict[x][i][:2] for x in main_dict.keys() for i in main_dict[x].keys()])
```

And it actually prints:

> [[1, 2], [4, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3]]

So what am I missing?

Comment: "Comprehension list" isn't a real term. You may have meant "list comprehension".

Answer (score 1):

You missed the square brackets:

```
self.logger.debug('Recieved: {}'.format([self.main_dict[x][i][:10] for x in self.main_dict.keys() for i in self.main_dict[x].keys()]))
```

Square brackets denote a list comprehension, and parentheses denote a generator expression.

Comment: By putting the square brackets I get:  `File "C:\...\local.py", line 161, in <listcomp>
    self.logger.debug('Received : {}'.format([self.main_dict[x][i][:10] for x in self.main_dict.keys() for i in self.main_dict[x].keys()]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @ZeCarioca That means there's a problem with your data.

Comment: True, just checked and there was an extra key in one of the subdict. However, now I have all the data inside a single list like this: `[[1, 2], [4, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3]]`. Is it possible to do it keeping the dictionary and keys? All i want is to reduce the size of the data.

Comment: @ZeCarioca Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in the same question. Post another question with a [mcve] and show your desired output.