# How to shorten this nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

This question is a continuation of this one: [Comprehension list and output <generator object.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002C392688C78>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757322/comprehension-list-and-output-generator-object-locals-genexpr-at-0x000002c3)

I was oriented to create a new question.
I have a few dicts inside another dict. And they get pretty big sometimes, since I'm keeping them in log I would like to limit the size of them to 30 'items' (key:value).

So I tried something like this: (In the example I limit the size to two)

```
main_dict = {
    'A':{
        'a1': [1,2,3],
        'a2': [4,5,6]
        },
    'B': {
        'b1': [0,2,4],
        'b2': [1,3,5]
        }
    }

print([main_dict[x][i][:2] for x in main_dict.keys() for i in main_dict[x].keys()])
```

The output I get is this:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

What I expected was this:

```
['A':['a1':[1, 2],'a2':[4, 5]], 'B':['b1':[0, 2], 'b2':[1, 3]]]
```

Or something like that. It doesn't have to be exactly that, but I need to know what value belongs to what dict, which isn't clear in the output I end up getting.

To put it simple all I want is to cut short the sub-dicts inside the dictionary. Elegantly, if possible.

Comment: `[]` is for lists, use `{}` for dicts

Comment: So for the item `'b1': [0,2,4]` that becomes `'b1':[0, 2]` , you just want to discard the `4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice clean way to do it in one line, without altering the original dictionary:

```
print({key: {sub_k: ls[:2] for sub_k, ls in sub_dict.items()} for key, sub_dict in main_dict.items()})
```

> Output:
>
> `{'A': {'a1': [1, 2], 'a2': [4, 5]}, 'B': {'b1': [0, 2], 'b2': [1, 3]}}`

Your original trial used list comprehension `[]`, but this case actually needs dict comprehension `{}`.

Comment: Had no idea dict comprehension existed. That worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @ZeCarioca glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print({key: {sub_key: lst[:2] for sub_key, lst in sub_dict.items()}
       for key, sub_dict in main_dict.items()})
```

Note the use of `{}` (dict comprehension) instead of `[]` (list comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach is to use nested `for` loops to delete the tail end of the sub-lists in-place:

```
for d in main_dict.values():
    for k in d:
        del d[k][2:]
```

`main_dict` becomes:

```
{'A': {'a1': [1, 2], 'a2': [4, 5]}, 'B': {'b1': [0, 2], 'b2': [1, 3]}}
```

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't want to shorten the dictionary itself, just the log.

Comment: Not ideal since OP wants to just log the shortened values, he probably wants to keep the original values untouched.

Comment: The OP specifically says "To put it simple all I want is to *cut short* the sub-dicts inside the dictionary. Elegantly, if possible." He/she does not say he/she needs the original values for anything else. To me the use of the phrase *cut short* means to delete the items in-place.

Comment: Still an easy fix even if you're wrong: `new_dict = main_dict` and then run your code on (and print) `new_dict`.

Comment: If a new list is needed then one should use comprehension. But given the OP's description I believe in-place deletion is what the OP desires.

Comment: @blhsing In the linked question, they say that the only purpose of this is to shorten log output of dicts they have received - to me this implies that they want to do something else with the dict after they have logged it. If modifying `main_dict` is fine, this is the way to go.

Comment: @B.Shefter that will not make a deep copy, just a new reference to the same dict, which will still be modified

Comment: @Phydeaux I see. I did not read the linked question. You could be right. It's up to the OP to decide the use case then.

Comment: @Phydeaux Arrrgh. You're right, of course. Can I downvote my own comment?

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't want to modify the dict, just short it for logging purposes. However I should have made that more clear. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'A':{
         'a1': [1,2,3],
         'a2': [4,5,6],
         'a3': [7,8,9]
         },
     'B':{
         'b1': [0,2,4],
         'b2': [1,3,5]
         }
     }
```

If the dictionaries are only nested *one-deep*

```
q = []
for k,v in d.items():
   keys, values = v.keys(), v.values()
   values = (value[:2] for value in values)
   q.append((k,tuple(zip(keys,values))))
```

Answer (score -2):

I have rewrote my code based on the comments provided. See below.

```
my_dict = {}

for key, value in main_dict.iteritems():
    sub_dict = {}
    for sub_key, sub_value in value.iteritems():
        sub_dict[sub_key] = sub_value[:2] 
    my_dict[key] = sub_dict

print my_dict
```

This will give you something that looks like this, and save it to a separate variable.

```
{'A': {'a1': [1, 2], 'a2': [4, 5]}, 'B': {'b1': [0, 2], 'b2': [1, 3]}}
```

Comment: This is not OP's desired output, and it edits `main_dict` in place which they probably don't want since they're doing this to print to a log file